# Python 3.5 ibm_db2 can't install

Tags: python-3.x, db2, database-connectivity

I'm quite new to python, but I need to connect with my python to a DB2. I'm trying to install the Python extension since a few hours and I can't get to a result.

When I'm installing the extension with

```
python ibm_db2 -- install
```

I get the following exception:

```
 /IBMDB2/CLIDRIVER//include folder not found. 
Check if you have set the IBM_DB_HOME environment variable's value correctly
```

But I can't find a folder including /include

I installed the ibm driver IBM Data Server Driver Package (DS Driver) V10.5
But also the SQLLIB folder has no /include folder.

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
Attached a screenshot of the driver folder: 
[Folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8aLP.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the Data Server Driver Package is sufficient -- as you have noticed, it does not contain developer tools, particularly the header files necessary for compilation. You may need to install the complete Data Server Client package.

Comment: Okay, i found the .h files in the folder of ibm_db2.zip. 
After the first try the cmd says it can't find dlls in ibm_db_dlls. 
Has somebody an idea?